# ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried creating a docker container using the command

`docker-compose up -d --build`

This is the outcome

```
Building api
Sending build context to Docker daemon  197.1kB
Step 1/10 : FROM python:3.11
 ---> cd9c1d09c087
Step 2/10 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> da58fbb74c86
Step 3/10 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65df5babfa13
Step 4/10 : RUN set -e;     apt-get update ;    apt-get -y install netcat ;    apt-get -y install gettext ;
 ---> Running in 07ea8396e874
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8906 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [4732 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [57.6 kB]
Fetched 9220 kB in 17s (531 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package netcat is a virtual package provided by:
  netcat-openbsd 1.219-1
  netcat-traditional 1.10-47

E: Package 'netcat' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c set -e;     apt-get update ;    apt-get -y install netcat ;    apt-get -y install gettext ;' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.7'
    services:

      api:
        build:
          context: ./drfproject
          dockerfile: docker/docker_files/Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - ./drfproject:/code
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        env_file:
          - .env

      app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: drfproject/docker/docker_files/Dockerfile_app
        platform: linux/amd64
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
```

I don't know where the issue lies, I tried to create a docker container but it failed please what can I do to fix this please where does the problem lies?

EDIT
The first issue has been solved but now it brings this error

```
ERROR: for drf_api_1  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What should be done

Comment: show the docker file for api

Answer (score 1):

Replace `apt-get -y install netcat` with `apt-get -y install netcat-traditional` in the Dockerfile

Comment: This works but another error was encountered while creating the api

ERROR: for drf_api_1  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: `chmod +x ./drfproject/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh`